# Thumbail does not show Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

On website: https://businessbay.pl/produkt/e-commerce-academy/
Thumbnail of product does not show here but when I click there it works. How can I fix that:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzFoO.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS in your style.css file

```
.storefront-full-width-content.single-product .t-szkolenie div.product .woocommerce-product-gallery{
   opacity:1 !important;
}
```